# PLSQL : What privilege to create temporary table

Tags: plsql, privileges

I would like to create a temporary table in a procedure in a package depending to user A.

I write this :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
  CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE T (....)';
```

I have an error saying :

```
ORA-01031 : Insufficient privilege
```

Selecting user_role_privs I can see that user A has this roles :

```
CONNECT
DBA
RESOURCE
```

What role, which is not contained in the previous ones, should I add to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: No - you do not create global temporary tables in your procedures. Create them once, then use them wherever required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A role is no use in definer-rights PL/SQL. You will need `create table` privilege granted directly.

Alternatively, do this in an invoker-rights package/procedure. However, invoker rights are best suited to 'generic utility' type code and not business data manipulation.

Why do you need to create tables in procedures? Can't you just include all the tables you need in the build?

Comment: Just to be sure to understand, I have to write the grant in the procedure ? a user would give a privilege to himself in the procedure ?

Comment: No, this would be part of the schema setup.

Comment: sorry I dont get it... this user does not have create table role already included in the 3 general roles it has ? By the way, I dont have any problem creating normal tables with this user in a sql script

Comment: Roles are for administering groups of end users, not for compiled code. Stored PL/SQL doesn't use roles. The application schema needs to have the appropriate privileges granted directly by a database administrator.

Comment: Finally i dont have the exception anymore if I create the package with AUTHID CURRENT_USER. Do y ou know what are the consequences ?

Comment: The resulting code would be less robust with the potential for runtime errors that would otherwise have been compilation errors. Using invoker rights to get around a missing grant is a hack. Why can't you have the appropriate privileges to build an application?